# $u$ is diagonalisable if and only if $\mathbb{K}[u]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{K}^d$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials

Let $E$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space on a field $\mathbb K$, $u$ an endomorphism of $E$, and $\pi_u$ its minimal polynomial of degree $d$.

I have this exercise :

> Show that $u$ is diagonalisable if and only if $\mathbb K [u]$ is isomorphic (as a $\mathbb K$-algebra) to $\mathbb K^d$.

If $u$ is diagonalisable, then its minimal polynomial can be written $\pi_u(X) = (X-\lambda_1) \dots (X- \lambda_d)$ with distinct $\lambda_i \in \mathbb K$.

And then :

$$ \mathbb K [u] \simeq \mathbb K[X]/(\pi_u) \simeq  \mathbb K[X]/(X- \lambda_1) \times \dots \times \mathbb K[X]/(X- \lambda_d) \simeq \mathbb K^d $$

I'm struggling to prove the other part of the assertion. If $\pi_u$ is not square-free then there would a nilpotent element $\mathbb K [u]$, but what if $\pi_u$ does not split in $\mathbb K$ ?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*. If $\pi$ doesn't split then $\mathbb{K}[u]$ contains a proper field extension of $\mathbb{K}$. OTOH, if an element of $\mathbb{K}^d$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{K}$ then all its components are roots of its minimal polynomial.